# How to run make in vim and open results in a split window?

Tags: vim, ide

I use vim for coding. When I have to compile the current file, Currently I use `:!g++ % && ./a.out` or `:make`.
The errors/output displayed are gone when I press enter and get back to the file. I wish the errors and output are displayed in a vertical split by the side. It would be nice if output and error streams are in separate buffers. How can this be done? 
Errors and Output buffer(s) should be updated when I compile again and it should not create new buffers.
How can do this? some vim pluggin/function? or a oneliner :P?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

oneliner:

```
:make | copen
```

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix-window

Comment: wow. great! Can I have a vertical split instead of a horizontal split?

Comment: @balki, try putting a `vert` just before the `copen`.

Comment: Yep, just use ``vert copen`` instead of ``copen``.  See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#opening-window for more info.

Comment: Thanks for vertical split. How do I use this quickfix window when compiling like this `:!g++ %` ?

Comment: Don't compile like that :) Instead, set `makeprg` and `errorformat` so the `:make` command will run g++ for you.  I'm not familiar with it but vim comes with a compiler configuration for gcc you might be able to start from.  See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#compiler-select

Comment: Jump between windows with Ctrl-w j (down) and Ctrl-w k (up), etc. If you're new to vim, you'll learn these quick.

Answer (score -1):

If you want compile and run if compile succeeded. (i.e `!g++ % && ./a.out` )

Create a shells script with the following line,

`g++ $1 -o /tmp/a.out && /tmp/a.out`

Now set the makeprg like this.
`set makeprg=compileNrun.sh\ %`

Cannot set the whole command directly as makeprg because of `&&`.
If set in makeprg directly, the above command will be expanded to,

`!g++ file.C -o /tmp/a.out && /tmp/a.out 2>&1 | tee /tmp/errorFile`

Hence compilation errors wont be redirected to the error file if compilation failed ;P as `&&` takes precedence over `|`

Comment: This answer does not address the problem to display compilation output in a (vertical) split